# Need help with ls and escape characters

Tags: ls, filenames

I'm trying to create a bash script to run the ffmpeg command on every file in a directory with filenames that contain spaces. This is the script that I started with to do an individual file which works properly. I use `tab` to populate the filename argument which includes an escape character for all the spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="./"$1
output="/xfer/transfer/temp/"$1
ffmpeg -i "${input}" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 160k "${output}"
```

Next step is to perform the ffmpeg command on all files in a directory. Let's say the directory looks like this with the `ls` command:

```
'Name of First File.mkv'
'Name of Second File.mkv'
```

Here's my test code:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(ls *)

for input in ${files}
do
   echo $input
done
```

My problem is the output looks like this:

```
Name
of
First
File.mkv
Name
Of
Second
File.mkv
```

Adding a `-b` to the ls command simply adds a backslash to the end of every line. I need help with making `$input` look like `Name of First File.mkv`, etc.

Comment: Like @Shelter usually says: good luck... **DO NOT USE `ls`** output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: `for file in *.txt`. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Learn how to quote properly in shell:

  > "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See    
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes>    
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments>    
<https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words>    
[when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, quote your parameters expansions and [do not loop through `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Unquoted file names could split if they contain any of the characters in the `IFS` shell variable.

The following code could solve your problem:

```
for file in *; do
    ffmpeg -i "${file}" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 160k "/xfer/transfer/temp/${file}"
done
```

Be careful when replacing the pattern in the loop; it may expand to a list of pathnames with slashes which would be concatenated with the string `/xfer/transfer/temp`. To prevent that, you may do the following:

```
for file in otherdirectory/*; do
    ffmpeg -i "${file}" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 160k "/xfer/transfer/temp/$(basename "${file}")"
done
```

If you need to recurse the directory even deeper, set the `globstar` option with the [`shopt` command builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).